# Varchar to eNum

Tags: mysql

I would like to convert a column in mysql from varchar to enum. If my new enum values include the existing values, will I lose existing values in that column?

Comment: With questions like this, the easiest answer is to try and find out. You can do this on a backup of the table to avoid the potential for data loss.

Comment: Will you blindly trust whatever you read here and risk losing the data?

Comment: Allow me to disagree with my follow programmers. I do believe that trivial but interesting questions have a space no SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, if the values are included in the enum you won't lose data.

Answer (score 22):

For copy paste junkies like myself, given the following output from PROCEDURE ANALYSE()

```
SELECT status FROM post PROCEDURE ANALYSE()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Field_name: crawling.post.status
              Min_value: done
              Max_value: pulled
             Min_length: 3
             Max_length: 6
       Empties_or_zeros: 0
                  Nulls: 0
Avg_value_or_avg_length: 3.7880
                    Std: NULL
      Optimal_fieldtype: ENUM('done','new','pulled') NOT NULL
```

And using the following command to convert my status column to enum:

```
ALTER TABLE post MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('done', 'new', 'pulled') DEFAULT 'new';
```

It's ok to skip the DEFAULT 'new'.